# Force Content Type with sendmail

Tags: bash, gmail, sendmail, content-type

I got a little problem when sending mail with sendmail: each mail are sent with `Content-Type: multipart/alternative` but I wonder to send my mail only in `Content-Type: text/plain`. The reason is because of GMAIL web interface respect the RFC, my message is displayed with the latest `Content-type` but because my message is not in HTML, the display is awful.

My bash script is as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

SENDMAIL_BIN='/usr/sbin/sendmail'
FROM_MAIL_ADDRESS='noreply@plop.com'
FROM_MAIL_DISLAY='Test format mail'
RECIPIENT_ADDRESSES='me@plop.com'

MAIL_CMD="$SENDMAIL_BIN -f $FROM_MAIL_ADDRESS -F \"$FROM_MAIL_DISLAY\" $RECIPIENT_ADDRESSES"
(echo "Subject: Test format";echo -e "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain;\n\n" && cat output.txt) | eval $MAIL_CMD
```

But my script doesn't seem to rewrite the `Content-Type` and it's still `Content-type: multipart/alternative` (according to the *show original* of my mail).

*nota*:

- There is nothing special in my output.txt (only log lines from my app).
- I tried a gruik hack: put a `<pre>` and `</pre>` but the display is still awful with `&lt;pre&gt;` in the source of the mail in the `Content-Type: text/html` part...

If you have any clue or if you know how to change the order of the `Content-Type` with sendmail let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a *non solution*, instead of to force my mail to be in `text/plain`, I will send a mail  in `text/html` but I will add the `<pre>` tag to open and close my output file... And because it's now in `text/html`, the `<pre>` tag is not displayed as `&lt;pre&gt;`

It's not what I excepted but it works. So my previous script simply become:

```
#!/bin/bash

SENDMAIL_BIN='/usr/sbin/sendmail'
FROM_MAIL_ADDRESS='noreply@plop.com'
FROM_MAIL_DISLAY='Test format mail'
RECIPIENT_ADDRESSES='me@plop.com'

MAIL_CMD="$SENDMAIL_BIN -f $FROM_MAIL_ADDRESS -F \"$FROM_MAIL_DISLAY\" $RECIPIENT_ADDRESSES"
(echo "Subject: Test format";echo -e "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html;\n" && echo '<pre>' && cat output.txt && echo '</pre>') | eval $MAIL_CMD
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra semicolon on the content type:

`echo -e "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n"`

Also it's better to use arrays than parse a string with eval:

```
#!/bin/bash

SENDMAIL_BIN='/usr/sbin/sendmail'
FROM_MAIL_ADDRESS='noreply@plop.com'
FROM_MAIL_DISLAY='Test format mail'
RECIPIENT_ADDRESSES='me@plop.com'

MAIL_CMD=("$SENDMAIL_BIN" -f "$FROM_MAIL_ADDRESS" -F "$FROM_MAIL_DISLAY" "$RECIPIENT_ADDRESSES")
(echo "Subject: Test format";echo -e "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n" && cat output.txt) | "${MAIL_CMD[@]}"
```

Comment: You right I forgot to remove a semicolon but even with your suggestion I got exactly the same behavior :(

Comment: Also try using just one \n since you only need one space (two newlines) between the header and the body or content: `text/plain\n"`. echo already produces one newline so having two \n's would give 3.

Comment: Still got the same behavior... I don't understand why I can't rewrite it

Comment: Are other headers appearing properly? did you try adding another fake header after content-type? (to my knowledge, your email reader will silently ignore any header that it cannot understand.)

Comment: Yes other headers are ok (for example the subject correctly appears). If I had a fake header like `Plop: mytest`, I see it in the *original*! I really don't understand how to do