# Linux sendmail chinese garbled

Tags: python, linux, sendmail

when i use sendmail in python to send some chinese(from a txt),it will be garbled in Email,
but use smtp to send , it is normal（true chinese).

```
def sendMail():
    filea= '/home/labs/temp/news.txt'
    with open(filea, 'r') as f:
        ne = f.read()
    # fileb='/home/labs/temp/send1.txt'    
    # with open(fileb, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:     
    #     news_info_str=','.join(news_info)
    #     f.write(news_info_str)
    sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location
    p = os.popen("%s -t" % sendmail_location, "w")
    p.write("From: %s\n" % "no-reply@redhat.com")
    p.write("To: %s\n" % "xxx@redhat.com")
    p.write("Subject: thesubject\n")
    p.write("\n") # blank line separating headers from body
    p.write(ne)
    status = p.close()
    print('fin')
```

Comment: Your own code contains the answer - UTF8. You'll have to specify the correct characterset with eg `-o message-charset="utf-8"` and the text you send has to be in that character set already. This may or may not be affected by the environments locale.  Why are you trying to use *sendmail* at all?

Comment: Add a content type header. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18233696/1216776